# Adding an .exe as a build step in Hudson

Tags: hudson

i'm busy configuring my `hudson` server for an `AS3` project.

I need a few steps to get to a succesful build.

1. get recent files from perforce
2. execute NAnt script
3. let hudson build project with the builder from flashdevelop
4. execute bat file

The only step that's giving me issues, is the 3th.

I don't know how I can tell hudson to use the my exe file and give the as3 project file as parameter.
The exe I need is: `C:\Program Files (x86)\FlashDevelop\Tools\fdbuild\fdbuild.exe`
and then I need to give my `.as3proj` file as parameter.

How can I add this build step to hudson? Is there a plugin to execute an exe file? Google didn't really give me a usefull answer :(

Kind regards and excuse me for my bad English :p

Answer (score 0):

You can execute arbitrary shell or windows batch command in Hudson/Jenkins. This command can of course include invocation of EXE (just like you would do the same from the command line). Here's screenshot of appropriate build step:

https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/download/attachments/753707/shell_script.jpg

However, I suggest you consider two (imo better suited) alternatives:

1. Consider having all your build steps in ANT, NANT or other build script of your choice. It is good practice to build your project in exactly the same way both with and without Hudson. Just let Hudson to pull the strings of your build script and properly manage resulting artifacts.
2. Rather than building with FlashDevelop builder, consider using MXMLC compiler directly. http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=compilers_13.html. Note that MXMLC compiler already has an ANT task. fdbuild.exe is merely a wrapper for MXMLC compiler. Or, to be more precise special version of this compiler shell (FCSH) that supports incremental builds.

Comment: The problem is, that this is a school assignment, given from a company. So they want us to use flashdevelop as coding an build tool.

Is there a way I can put the exe and as3proj file link in a bat file or some other type of script to execute that step?

Comment: Just enter "C:\Program Files (x86)\FlashDevelop\Tools\fdbuild\fdbuild.exe" "c:/fullpath/to_project.as3proj" (as one line) into that step. In exactly the same way as you would enter that in Windows Command Line.

Comment: Derp, that worked out offcourse. Yet again hudson is bugging me with the final step.

I'm adding the bat file as a build step, and hudson is whining about the path not being correct. X is placeholder name, hence i'm under an NDA ;)

C:\Hudson\jobs\X\workspace>X\XApp\PackageApp.bat
The system cannot find the path specified.

i'm a bit confused with the > hudson put's there by itself.

So the bat file I need is 2 folders down in the workspace (X\XApp\batfile)

Comment: Glad it is starting to work! I guess from this moment it will be fare if you take it yourself. After all this is a school assignment, in real life build scripts will be 10x more complex. :) Basic direction: figure out a story of relative/absolute paths in hudson.

Comment: I understand that, but i'm getting frustrated that the hudson server still doesn't work propperly. It's costing me precious coding time :p

Comment: The builds scripts and stuff are not written by me, they are given by the company. All we have to do, is write code and set up that server (wich is like 5% of the assignment)

I'm just not figuring out why it doesn't work. For the nant script, it's also a relative path to the workspace, and that works, but for this bat file it doesn't? It's confusing me...

I have tried every possible path combination, even with / and \ and ../ and stuff, no help.

Comment: @user2190876 If this is still a problem, you should edit this question to include stuff in these comments, or if it has turned into a new question, ask a new question.

Comment: Oh, and at a glance, that > there seems like command prompt, with working directory left of it and command on the right, but it is hard to know without proper formatting.